# What is the best approach to interacting with map layers after a JTX Job Change event when a new MXD is loaded?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-workflow-manager

To further clarify, my question is pertaining to a WMX/JTX job activation from within ArcMap, not Workflow Manager.

I have a JTXJobListener class where with a `JobChanged` method and that is successfully called.  My problem is with the event order.  I can do whatever I want with the map, but if that WMX/JTX job loads a MXD...I lose those changes (changes are on the original map not the new one that is loaded).  I'm in need of an event that fires after the job type MXD is loaded into ArcMap.

Am I missing an event that I can use?  If not, what are the typical workaround(s) to this issue? Hack it using the document events??